# Wird die temporale Präposition "über+AKK" im Satz "die ganze Arbeit" vor- oder nachgestellt?

Tags: preposition

Ich habe gelesen und gelernt, dass die temporale Präposition "über+AKK" in den folgenden Sätze nachgestellt wird:

> Den ganzen Tag über habe ich geschlafen
>
> Die ganze Zeit über hast du gar nichts gemacht

Jetz frage ich mich, sind die folgenden Sätze möglich? Wenn nein, wie wird die Präposition "über" in Sätze richtig gestellt? Vor oder nach "die ganze Arbeit"?

> Die ganze Arbeit über habe ich geschlafen
>
> Über die ganze Arbeit hast du gar nichts gemacht

Comment: Nein, _die ganze Arbeit über_ geht nicht. (Und _über die ganze Arbeit_ sowieso nicht.)

Comment: @chirlu Doch, umgangssprachlich ist das mindestens regional akzeptabel. _Arbeit_ steht dann für ‚Arbeitszeit‘ oder auch für ‚Dauer der Klassenarbeit‘.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die korrektere Variante von beiden, wäre die erste

> Die ganze Arbeit über habe ich geschlafen

Hier gilt dieselbe Regel wie bei deinen anderen Beispielen. *Über* am Anfang des Satzes hingegen verliert seine temporale Bedeutung und wird lokal. Das ergibt bei *Arbeit* aber keinen Sinn.

Die erste Variante ist also zumindest syntaktisch die richtige bzw. gleichbedeutend zu deinen anderen Beispielen. Da *Arbeit* aber kein Zeitbegriff ist, leidet die Semantik auch hier. Ein besserer Ausdruck wäre:

> Während der Arbeit habe ich (die ganze Zeit) geschlafen.

Kleine Ergänzung am Rande: es heißt *die* Präposition.

Comment: also kann ich den Satz "Ich habe über die ganze Arbeit geschlafen" bilden?

Comment: Nein, das ist auch falsch. Du solltest *über* generell nur mit Nomen verwenden, die eine lokale, oder wie hier, temporale Präposition nehmen. Der bessere Ausdruck wäre „Ich habe während der Arbeit die ganze Zeit (über) geschlafen“, oder wenn's auch kürzer sein darf: „Ich habe während der Arbeit geschlafen.“

Comment: ich versuche zu kapieren.. Nehmen wir dein Beispiel „Ich habe während der Arbeit die ganze Zeit (über) geschlafen“, und bilden wir den Satz mit dem Präposition "über" "Ich habe die ganze Zeit über geschlafen", warum wird "über" nachgestellt? Du hast geschrieben "Hier gilt dieselbe Regel wie bei deinen anderen Beispielen. Über am Anfang des Satzes hingegen verliert seine temporale Bedeutung und wird lokal.", und im Beispielsatz steht "über" nicht am Anfang des Satzes.. oder kapiere ich etwas nicht?

Comment: Es wird nachgestellt, wenn man einen Zeitraum beschreiben will. Also "die Zeit über", "die Woche über", "das Jahr über" etc. Angenommen, man interpretiert *Arbeit* als einen Zeitraum (also quasi 9-17 Uhr), dann wäre es dementsprechend auch "die Arbeit über". Ich habe den Ausdruck auch schon häufiger gehört, er ist also zumindest in der Umgangssprache nicht wirklich falsch. Aber wirklich richtig ist er auch nicht, denn eigentlich ist *Arbeit* kein Zeitbegriff.

Comment: pardon, ich versuche noch mal dich zu verstehen..
bei canoo http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html?MenuId=Word733#Anchor-14549 lese ich "Wir bleiben über das Wochenende hier", das Wochenende hat 2 Tagen und es ist ein Zeitraum auch.. (anderes Bespiel: http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=87#zeitdauer )

Comment: Man kann es auch davor stellen, aber nachgestellt klingt es besser. Ich würde eher "das Wochenende über"  sagen. "Über das Jahr" ist auch korrekt, aber "das Jahr über" klingt besser. *Über* am Anfang ist gängiger bei lokaler Bedeutung, z.B. in "Ich gehe über die Brücke". Hier würde man niemals sagen "Ich gehe die Brücke über".

Comment: in Ordnung, jetzt ist es mir klar ;)

Comment: Bei deinem zweiten Link ist das Beispiel "wir wollen übers Wochenende...". Um die Verwirrung perfekt zu machen: wenn man *über* und *das* zu *übers* zusammenzieht, dann muss es davor stehen. "Wochenende übers" geht nicht.

Comment: Interessanter Fall von vorangestelltem, aber zeitlichem "über". Mein Sprachgefühl sieht da einen subtilen Bedeutungsunterschied zum Nachgestellten "Über": "Über's Wochenende fahren wir weg", "über Weihnachten sind wir bei Oma"  usw. bezeichnet eine Transition, einen Übergang von davor zu danach; während "das Wochenende über sind wir weg" eher bloß den Zeitraum bedeutet. Aber das ist schon ein sehr zarter Unterschied...

Comment: Ja, das ist tatsächlich ein sehr feiner Unterschied. Ich könnte daraus jetzt aber keine wirklich allgemeingültige Regel ableiten.